# adding entries to a dictionary if it doesn't exist already

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I'm trying to write some code that calculates powers of 2 but stores them in a dictionary that has powers of 10 as the key, so for example, 2^9 would be stored as

```
{0:2, 1:1, 2:5}
```

where you have 5*10^2 + 1*10^1 + 2*10^0.

So currently, I have something like

```
def foo():
    result={0:2}
    for i in range(2,10):
        for p in result.keys():
            result[p]*=2
        for p in result.keys():
            if result[p] / 10 != 0:
                result.setdefault(p+1,result[p]/10)
                result[p] = result[p] % 10
```

The issue is

```
result.setdefault(p+1,result[p]/10)
```

It overwrites whatever was in `result[p+1]`.  I know it's possible to just check the dictionary and then "initialize" the new key if needed, but is there a more elegant way to do it on the fly?  I could initialize result to be long enough, but since I don't necessarily know how long is "long enough", it seems to me to make more sense to extend it on the fly.

Basically I'd like something along the lines of

```
for p in result.keys():
    if result[p] / 10 != 0:
        if result[p+1] exists:
            result[p+1]+=result[p]/10
        else:
            create result[p+1] and set its value to result[p]/10
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your code as posted is setting `result[p]`, not `result[p+1]`.

Comment: Quick question: Why are you using a dict `{0:2, 1:1, 2:5}` instead of a list `[2, 1, 5]`? Either way, `x[0]==2`, `x[1]==1`, `x[2]==5`.

Comment: @Amber: sorry, I don't quite understand, my goal was to set {0:16} to {0:6, 1:1}, so I have to change both...

Comment: @abarnert: just trying to learn/practicing the basics of how to use dictionaries :)

Comment: OK. You're talking about more than the basics here, but I suppose "learning the intermediates of how to use dictionaries" is just as good a reason to make things harder on yourself than learning the basics. :) I just wanted to point out that you're using a `dict` as a mapping from a non-sparse initial set of natural numbers to values, and that's exactly what a `list` is, out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you're doing each time through the main loop is: double each digit, then carry extra tens to the next digit. The problem is that, for the highest digit, the next digit doesn't exist.

So here's a solution—although it's not going to work for any power other than 2, for reasons I'll get to below.

```
def foo():
    result={0:2}
    for i in range(2,10):
        for p in result.keys():
            result[p]*=2
        for p in result.keys()[:]:
            if result[p] / 10 != 0:
                result[p+1] = result.get(p+1, 0) + result[p] / 10
                result[p] = result[p] % 10
```

There are two key changes from your original code.

First, we had to add `[:]` to the end of the second `result.keys()`, to iterate over a copy of the dictionary's set of keys before the loop, rather than its current keys. The reason is that if the last digit is >5 we're going to be adding a new key to the dictionary, and you're not allowed to do that while iterating over it. (Why? A few reasons, but the simple one is that dictionaries are in arbitrary order, and every time you add a key, the whole order can change. This will be important later, too.)

Second, there's your original question: How can you avoid having to check `if p+1 in result` to decide whether to store `r_p` or add `r_p` to the existing value?

When you're dealing with counts, you use `collection.Counter`, which is like a `dict` except that it only stores integers, and any missing key has a value of 0. Otherwise, you usually use `collection.defaultdict`, which is like a `dict` except that you can specify an default value that all missing keys have. With either a `Counter` or `defaultdict`, all you'd need is `result[p+1] += result[p]/10`.

But I've used a different alternative: the `get` method on the `dict`, which lets you specify a default value. I'll explain why later, but keep in mind that in general, when you find yourself reaching for `get`, you may want a `defaultdict` or `Counter` instead.

So, now it'll run, and work, for powers of 2. But it won't work for other powers, for two reasons:

First, we're doing the carries in random order. For powers of 2, the most you could carry is a 1, and there's no way a 1 could affect whether the next digit up carries. (8 won't carry and neither will 8+1, and there's now way to get a 9.) But for any other power, that isn't true.

In simple testing, you might not notice this, because it just so happens that (at least in CPython 2.7 and 3.2) when you start with an empty `dict` and add a small number of small keys (actually, keys with small hash values, but small ints hash to themselves) in sorted order, and don't delete anything, the `dict` will often iterate (and print) in order. But in general, the order is not predictable, and you can't rely on it.

The solution to that problem is to use `collections.OrderedDict`, which iterates over the keys in the order in which they were added. And that's why I didn't want to use `defaultdict` or `Counter`: because if you have to switch to `OrderedDict`, your only option is `get`.

Second, once your exponent gets over 10, you may need to carry 100. That means you have to carry the 10, which will cause the next digit to carry even if it's 0. That means that we can't just copy the keys in advance. For example, let's say we're doing powers of 75. Start off with `{0:5, 1:7}`. Multiply each digit by 75 to `{0:375, 1:525}`. Now carry the 37: `{0:5, 1:562}`. Now carry the 56: `{0:5, 1:2, 2:56}`. Because we were only iterating over a copy of the original keys—that is, `[0, 1]`—we don't get a chance to carry the 5.

I'll leave it up to you to fix that problem.

However, one thing you might want to consider is creating a new dictionary, instead of modifying the old one in place. Then you can get around all of these problems. (As a general rule, using pure functions instead of mutating state gets around a lot of problems, but of course at the cost of extra copying.)

```
def double(d):
    result = Counter()
    for p in d:
        result[p] += d[p] % 10
        result[p+1] += d[p] / 10
    return result

digits={0:2}
for i in range(2,10):
    for p in digits:
        digits[p]*=2
    digits = double(digits)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the elaborate answer! There are a lot of concepts here to go through...

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the existence of a key by using the `in` syntax:

```
for p in result.keys()[:]:
    r_p = result[p] / 10

    if r_p != 0:
        if p + 1 in result:
            result[p + 1] += r_p
        else:
            result[p + 1] = r_p
```

Or, you can use `Counter`, which automatically does this:

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter()

for p in result.keys()[:]:
    r_p = result[p] / 10

    if r_p != 0:
        result[p + 1] += r_p
```

Also, your condition is a little strange. `result[p] / 10 == 0` only if `result[p] < 10` on Python 2 or `result[p] == 0` on Python 3.

Comment: +1 for `Counter`. But the first version would be much simpler as: `result[p + 1] = result.get(p + 1, 0) + r_p` instead of the `if:`/`else:` loop.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks. I should start using `.get()` more often.

Comment: Well, half the time you reach for `get` you realize that `Counter`, `defaultdict`, or `try:`/`d[key]…`/`except:` is a better answer anyway…

Comment: Blender, @abarnert: I tried your solutions but they both throw a "dictionary changed size during iteration" error.  Is there something that I'm missing?  Would I need to use a temp dictionary to use your solutions?

Comment: Right, sorry, that's going to happen, because every time you add a new value, you're changing the dictionary's set of keys, which changes the iteration order, which makes the iteration invalid. (Note: this wouldn't happen with a list…) Anyway, if you know the dict is going to be pretty small (and it is, unless you're dealing with insanely huge numbers), a really easy fix is to copy the list of initial keys: `for p in result.keys()[:]`. (Is it actually correct for your algorithm, or do you need carry semantics? I haven't read it carefully…)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the phrase "carry semantics" -- could you explain?  Also, just to compare notes on the list solution (which I also wrote), I had to use a `try` statement: `try: result[i+1] += result[i]/10; except: result.append(result[i]/10)`, or do you have a better way?

Comment: I get what you're doing. It's too long to explain what I mean here, so let me write an answer.

Comment: For a list, I think what I'd do is just append a 0 onto the end before the loop. But I guess what you _really_ want is something kind of like `defaultdict` called `defaultlist`, where `d[n]` automatically extends `d` to size `n` and fills the new slots with your default value (0, in this case). It wouldn't be at all hard to write such a class.